# Fitting method for non-linear function with experimental data

Tags: matlab, global, func

I want to fit the non-linear function (variation is T) with experimental data.
In here, I used `lsqcurvefit`, but I don’t know the exact principle of this function, and even I don't know how to use the command `func`, also. (so the script I wrote is bad.)

For this, how can I modify the script below?
(even w/o using `lsqcurve` fit, I don’t care. Chi-square, least-square, any form is okay.)
Code is as follows (3 parts):

```matlab
%script 1
x=coefficient1
y=coefficient2
z=coefficient3
A1=x*0.321*T
A2=(y/0.2)+0.5*T
A3=(z+0.3)*0.17/T

%script 2
global A1
global A2
global A3
Result=(A1+0.3)*A2+0.3

%script 3
global Result

Sample=readmatrix(‘experimentaldata’);
XX=sample(1,:)’;
YY=sample(2,:)’;
Xdata=linespace(min(XX),max(XX),2000);
Yadata=(interpl(XX,YY,xdata);
Fitting=lsqscurvefit(Result,T,xdata,ydata,250,2000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid if I had mistake while understanding your script (including bizarre global variables and coefficients...). But until now it seems to me that you want to fit your data into quadratic polynomial (considering T as single variable and x,y,z as constant, inserting A1 & A2 to your Result gives quadratic polynomial)

```
%Result = (x*0.321*T+0.3)*((y/0.2)+0.5*T)+0.3
Result = @(c,T)c(1)*T^2+c(2)*T^3+c(3);
```

Here, your final equation form will be as above, c stands for your constant, and T stands for your variable(or xdata).
After you clarify your equation form, you should set your initial state of constant c. In *lsqcurve*, as given in their explanation, they find their final answer by iterating until error(or euclidean distance) becomes smaller than given criteria. Therefore setting valid initial value will be critical here, if not answer will converge to local minimum (you can refer to John's perfect answer about this issue here, [curve fitting error:nlinfit rank deficient](https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/434706-curve-fitting-error-nlinfit-rank-deficient)).

```
c0=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
```

But in this case I'll just randomly give initial value as above.
Afterward, answer(or c) is ready to be calculated

```
Fitting=lsqscurvefit(Result,c0,xdata,ydata)
```

Other matlab's non-linear fitting function including *nlinfit* have similar workflow. I think you can simply understand more detailed information about them if you take more attention to their description.

But personally, I recommend you to use matlab's *polyfit* if your final equation form is in polynomial. You don't have to take care tuning your initial value then...

Comment: Actually, that script is just an example, and what I want to coding is a very long formula(include over 30 kinds of coefficients, also), so it is difficult to express it as a single polynomial.  Anyway, your answer is so helpful. I'll try it using what you answered and the nonlinearfit function.  Thanks for the kind explanation.